# Apply rolling function which generates a list of data.frames (or single rbinded data.frame)

Tags: r, rolling-computation, rollapply

The two most commonly used functions for rolling functions (that I'm aware of) are `zoo::rollapply` and `data.table::frollapply()`.

However, neither seems capable of running a function which generates a data.frame for each step and then returning them either in a list or as a single `rbind`-ed data.frame.

As a trivial example, if I have a function which simply returns a trivial data.frame and I call it with a rolling function, I'd expect to get:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  data.frame(a = LETTERS[x], b = x)
}

# will be called twice, with inputs 1:2 and 2:3.
myrollapply(1:3, n = 2, FUN = f)
#> [[1]]
#>   a b
#> 1 A 1
#> 2 B 2
#>
#> [[2]]
#>   a b
#> 1 B 2
#> 2 C 3
#>
#> -- OR --
#> 
#>   a b
#> 1 A 1
#> 2 B 2
#> 3 B 2
#> 4 C 3
```

(for those who're interested, my real use-case rolls through a vector (or list, if necessary) of dates and then calls an external API which returns tabular data. Due to a restriction of the API, I can't do everything at once and must make multiple calls to the API to get what I need. My end goal would be to collate all the data.frames I get from the API into a single `rbind`-ed data.frame.)

This seems impossible with `zoo` and `data.table`:

`zoo` seems to not allow lists as `zoo` objects, which impedes their use as input or output. And if the function returns a naked data.frame, the output seems to do an `rbind` of transposed versions of the individual data.frames (also, the output is a matrix, not a data.frame, which isn't acceptable).

```r
zoo::rollapply(c(1, 2, 3),
               width = 2,
               FUN = function(x) {data.frame(a = 1:3)})
#>      a1 a2 a3
#> [1,]  1  2  3
#> [2,]  1  2  3

zoo::rollapply(data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3)),
               width = 2,
               FUN = function(x) {data.frame(a = 1:3)})
#>      a
#> [1,] 1
#> [2,] 1
#> [3,] 2
#> [4,] 2
#> [5,] 3
#> [6,] 3

zoo::rollapply(c(1, 2, 3),
               width = 2,
               FUN = function(x) {list(data.frame(a = 1:3))})
#> Error in zoo(do.call("c", dat), index(data)[ix], attr(data, "frequency")) : 
#>   “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object

zoo::rollapply(list(1, 2, 3),
               width = 2,
               FUN = function(x) {data.frame(a = 1:3)})
#> Error in zoo(data) : “x” : attempt to define invalid zoo object
```

With `data.table::frollapply`, the problem is easier to understand: the return value must be numeric (or castable to numeric).

```r
data.table::frollapply(c(1, 2, 3), n = 2, FUN = function(x) {data.frame(a = 1:3)})
#> Error in data.table::frollapply(c(1, 2, 3), n = 2, FUN = function(x) { : 
#>   frollapply: results from provided FUN are not of type double
```

Is there a package or method which can handle this particular case? I'm currently doing it by hand with a for-loop, but suspect there may be a better, more R-like solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Run `rollapply` on the indexes and then use `apply`.

```
library(zoo)

f <- function(x) data.frame(a = LETTERS[x], b = x)
ii <- rollapply(1:3, 2, c)
apply(ii, 1, f)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
  a b
1 A 1
2 B 2

[[2]]
  a b
1 B 2
2 C 3
```

**2)** This also works:

```
L <- list()
junk <- rollapply(1:3, 2, function(x, i = x[1]) L[[i]] <<- f(x))
L
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
  a b
1 A 1
2 B 2

[[2]]
  a b
1 B 2
2 C 3
```

**3)** Another approach is to compute on the language.

```
s <- rollapply(1:3, 2, function(x) sprintf("f(c(%s))", toString(x)))
lapply(s, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
  a b
1 A 1
2 B 2

[[2]]
  a b
1 B 2
2 C 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sequences to the rescue:

```
## window and number
w <- 2
n <- 2

## generate sequence
s <- rep(seq_len(w)) + rep(seq.int(0, n-1), each=w)

f(s)
#  a b
#1 A 1
#2 B 2
#3 B 2
#4 C 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple rolling slice function :)

```
roll_slice <- function(x, w, s){
    #' w: window size
    #' s: step size
    embed(x, w)[seq(1, length(x) - w + 1, by = s), rev(seq_len(w))]
}

apply(roll_slice(c(1, 2, 3), 2, 1), 1, f)
# [[1]]
#   a b
# 1 A 1
# 2 B 2
# 
# [[2]]
#   a b
# 1 B 2
# 2 C 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your own rolling function with `lapply` :

```
val <- 1:3
k <- 2
lapply(seq_along(head(val, -(k-1))), function(x) f(val[x:(x+k-1)]))

# [[1]]
#  a b
#1 A 1
#2 B 2

#[[2]]
#  a b
#1 B 2
#2 C 3
```

Another example -

```
val <- 1:5
k <- 3
lapply(seq_along(head(val, -(k-1))), function(x) f(val[x:(x+k-1)]))

# [[1]]
#  a b
#1 A 1
#2 B 2
#3 C 3

#[[2]]
#  a b
#1 B 2
#2 C 3
#3 D 4

#[[3]]
#  a b
#1 C 3
#2 D 4
#3 E 5
```